# Force compile-time calculations C

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

Let's say that I have a file, in which I do some calculations on some data. It could be (very psedo calculations) like this:

```
void hash_value(unsigned char* value){
    unsigned char i;
    for(i + 0; i < 10; i++){
        value[i] ^= (0x1b+i)
    }
}

void break_value(unsigned char* value){
    unsigned char i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        value[i] &= 0x82;
}

void affect_value(unsigned char* value){
    hash_value(value);
    break_value(value);
}
```

In my main I would the do the following:

```
#include "smart_calculations.h"

int main() {
    unsigned char value[16] = {'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S', 'S'};
    affect_value(value);
    // Do other stuff

}
```

Since I do not intend to change the contents of the value array, but I need to do the calculations before I can continue doing other stuff. I guess that some compilers will recognize the, and optimize the code, such that the data is computed at compiletime.

My question is, how do I (as best possible) force the compiler to do this optimization at compiletime, such that methods in the "Smart_calculations" file isn't wasting space in the final product, and the initial values of the array isn't compiled in to the program?

Comment: You could add the `constexpr` keyword to any constant value expressions, and then use a C++ compiler.

Comment: You could declare the functions `inline`, this is a hint to the compiler that it should merge the code into the caller, which could do what you want.

Comment: @schulmaster I'm aware, but unfortuanly I need to use pure, good ol', C for this :)

Comment: You could preprocess the data and write the results to a header file containing the hashed values. Put this into your build script or makefile.

Comment: You can write them out, e.g. for the first 2 values of `value[16]` that would be `'S' ^ (0x1b+0), 'S' ^ (0x1b+1), ..` just as long as they are constant expressions.

Comment: Wrote another program that will calculate the values and generate a header files. Then your program needs to include that generated header file with the precomputed values (I did that once). If your calculations can be inserted into a constant expression, it is the only way you can force the compiler to precalculate them using  C preprocessor.

Comment: You have an bug and undefined behavior in the code you posted, probably `for(i + 0; i < 10; i++){` should be `for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){`.

Comment: You must do this yourself as other commenters say. Array cannot be created during compile time.

Comment: @purec: Reading an uninitialised variable may very well invoke UB.

Comment: @alk, yes, you are right, I am not very confident with undefined behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest, most general method is to do your staging manually. That is, run the code that does the pre-calculations explicitly during your build phase and only compile the results into your program.

If you want to do it all in C, you'd create a `smart_calculations.c` with a `main` function. You'd first compile a `smart_calculations` executable that produces

```
unsigned char value[16] = { ... };
```

as output. Place this output in a file, e.g. `smart_generated.h`.

Your real program would then either `#include` this file:

```
int main() {
    #include "smart_generated.h"  // 'value' is now a local variable
    // Do other stuff    
}
```

... or (if you want a global variable instead) you'd put the generated results in a `.c` file and link it into your program.

Of course with this approach you're not limited to doing the "smart calculations" in C. You can use any programming language or environment that's available at build time.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. 
Since I'm writing to a microcontroller, I'm storing as much constant data in programspace as possible, hence I would like to avoid having a header containing the data. 

I know this is out of scope of the question, but is it possible to read from the generated file in compiletime, such that I can put it in programspace? :)

Comment: @BenjaminLarsen I've never touched a microcontroller, but your question makes no sense. `#include` is literally reading from files at compile time. What is "programspace"?

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to setup a build-chain, but I could just do that using CMake. It solved my problem, thanks :)